# Simple "kiosk" - StartX with one application says no protocol specified

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, vlc, startx, kiosk

My aim is to have a Ubuntu laptop which starts one application and the users can't use the mouse or keyboard.

First thing to do was find out the command to start the program.
This is this command.

```
export DISPLAY=:0 && pidof cvlc 2>/dev/null >/dev/null || cvlc --fullscreen --no-video-title-show rtsp://192.168.1.2:554/onvif
```

Then I tried to stop autologin and loading the graphical ui.

```
# /etc/init/lightdm.override
manual
```

So but then if I want to `startx -- :0` then it shows me the plain background. That's great.
But then if I execute the first command of this topic I get

```
VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower (revision 2.0.8a-0-g68cf50b)
[0x1a26bf8] inhibit interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: //bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.

[0x1a26bf8] main interface error: no suitable interface module
No protocol specified
[0x1a26a38] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x17f7108] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0x1a26bf8] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[0x7ff654002a58] live555 demux error: SETUP of'video/H264' failed 500 Internal Server Error
[0x7ff654002a58] live555 demux error: SETUP of'audio/PCMA' failed 500 Internal Server Error
```

And if startx is not started then I get this.

```
VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower (revision 2.0.8a-0-g68cf50b)
[0x1037bf8] inhibit interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: //bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.

[0x1037bf8] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x1037a38] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0xe08108] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0x1037a38] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[0x7f05ec0010d8] live555 demux error: SETUP of'video/H264' failed 500 Internal Server Error
[0x7f05ec0010d8] live555 demux error: SETUP of'audio/PCMA' failed 500 Internal Server Error
```

And this is a successful start if I enable autologin and start the vlc player via crontab for example.

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && pidof cvlc 2>/dev/null >/dev/null || cvlc --fullscreen --no-video-title-show rtsp://192.168.1.2:554/onvif
```

Small output but everything works fine.

```
VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower (revision 2.0.8a-0-g68cf50b)
[0x24df238] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
```

Do somebody know how to solve this?

It's a Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (Precise Pangolin) laptop.